# What does "-tu" mean?

Tags: pronoms-personnels

I have listened to Édith Piaf's [*Johny tu n'es pas un ange*](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/edithpiaf/johnnytunespasunange.html) and she says

> Toi, te souviens-tu de moi.

What is *-tu*?

BTW, I do know what *tu* is, but not *-tu*, and have not found it on Google, perhpaps it does not count the dash (-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Se souvenir*** is a reflexive verb. Two pronouns are used, they represent the same person because in such verbs, the subject acts on themselves.

> Je me souviens (literally: I remind myself)
> Tu te souviens
> Il/elle/on se souvient
> Nous nous souvenons
> [...]

In the interrogative form, the subject pronoun is inversed but not the object one:

> Me souviens-je de... ? (rare)
> Te souviens-tu de... ?
> Se souvient-il/elle/on de... ?
> Nous souvenons-nous de... ?
> [...]

Finally, ***Toi*** is used in the sentence to emphasize the fact she is talking to Johnny, so ***toi***, ***te*** and ***tu*** all refer to the same person.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused because the subjective was enclitic, which does not make sense in Portuguese. It is actually similar to English: "Have you done this?" compared to "You have done this.",

Comment: Right. In casual/oral French, the inversion is rarer and rarer: *Toi, tu te souviens de moi ?*